# Flask-Sqlalchemy: filter rows where column contains a certain object

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following database setup:

```
abcs = db.Table('abcs',
    db.Column('hero_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('hero.id')),
    db.Column('player_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('player.id')),
    db.Column('game_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('game.id'))
)

class Player(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    account_id = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False, unique=True)

class Hero(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    hero_id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True)
    localized_name = db.Column(db.String)
    url_small_portrait = db.Column(db.String)
    url_large_portrait = db.Column(db.String)
    url_full_portrait = db.Column(db.String)
    url_vertical_portrait = db.Column(db.String)

class Game(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    mmr = db.Column(db.Integer)
    server_steam_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    match_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    lobby_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    activate_time = db.Column(db.Integer)
    deactivate_time = db.Column(db.Integer)
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer)
    has_pro = db.Column(db.Integer, default=-1)
    radiant_win = db.Column(db.Integer)

    players = db.relationship("Player", secondary = abcs, lazy='subquery',
        backref=db.backref('games', lazy=True))
    heroes = db.relationship("Hero", secondary = abcs, lazy='subquery',
        backref=db.backref('games', lazy=True))
```

Which means whenever I add an entry to the table 'Game', Game.players will return a list with objects of the type 'Player'.

Now what I would like to do is to make a query of the form

```
p = Player.query.filter(P.account_id == 12345).first()
games = Game.query.filter(*get all games where Game.players contain p*).all()
```

My first naive approach for the 2nd line was

```
games = Game.query.filter(Game.players.contains(p)).all()
```

and that DOES return all entries from 'Game' where Game.players contains p, BUT for some reason, using *.contains* changes the order of elements in every row's .players, so for example the list

```
games[0].players
```

has now a different order compared to the situation where I would query that particular game directly.

So basically, I'm asking how I can achieve what I would like to do - how can I query all games in the table Game that contain a specific Player?

Comment: Not sure but I believe `=` should be a better option here for filtering. Also, is `order_by` you are actually looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Use `order_by` in your queries to guarantee you get a predictable order. For example

```
games = Game.query.filter(Game.players.contains(p)).order_by(Game.some_field).all()
```